Why are my Java multi-thread I/O slower than sequential?
While testing thread creation/parallel processing, I met this strange situation where the multi-thread code is much slower than sequential version.
The code is simply counting words in files, then summing the result.
Sequential code :
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class WordCount {

    public static int countWords(String filename) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            int total = 0;
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                total += line.split("\\s+").length;
            }
            System.out.println("Time for file "+filename+" : "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) + " ms for "+ total + " words");
            return total;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int [] wordCount = new int[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            try {
                wordCount[i] = countWords(args[i]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error reading file: " + args[i]);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Word count:" + Arrays.toString(wordCount));
        int total = 0;
        for (int count : wordCount) {
            total += count;
        }
        System.out.println("Total word count:" + total);
        System.out.println("Total time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) + " ms");
    }
}

This is the version that runs one thread per file.
public class WordCountMT {

    public static int countWords(String filename) throws IOException {
        // same code
    }

    private static class CounterWorker implements Runnable {
        private String filename;
        private int index;
        private int[] wordCount;

        public CounterWorker(String filename, int index, int[] wordCount) {
            this.filename = filename;
            this.index = index;
            this.wordCount = wordCount;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                wordCount[index] = countWords(filename);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error reading file: " + filename);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int[] wordCount = new int[args.length];
        List<Thread> th = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            th.add(new Thread(new CounterWorker(args[i], i, wordCount)));
            th.get(i).start();
        }
        try {
            for (Thread t : th) {
                t.join();

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Word count:" + Arrays.toString(wordCount));
        int total = 0;
        for (int count : wordCount) {
            total += count;
        }
        System.out.println("Total word count:" + total);
        
        System.out.println("Total time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) + " ms");
    }
}

Ok, so it's a very basic example used for teaching. Now I could understand that creating a lot of threads is sometimes counter productive, but these traces are strange :
Non MT
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-5.txt : 14 ms for 1468 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-6.txt : 3 ms for 1468 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5.txt : 1 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-5.txt : 1 ms for 780 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data7.txt : 1 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6.txt : 2 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-6.txt : 2 ms for 2156 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data8.txt : 1 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data3.txt : 0 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-7.txt : 1 ms for 2156 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data4.txt : 1 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-4.txt : 1 ms for 780 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data1.txt : 0 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data2.txt : 0 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data9.txt : 1 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-7.txt : 0 ms for 1468 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-4.txt : 1 ms for 1468 words
    Word count:[1468, 1468, 390, 780, 1078, 1078, 2156, 1078, 390, 2156, 390, 780, 390, 390, 1078, 1468, 1468]
    Total word count:18006
    Total time 54 ms

With MT
    Time for file /tmp/data/data3.txt : 46 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-4.txt : 54 ms for 780 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-5.txt : 58 ms for 780 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data1.txt : 45 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-5.txt : 70 ms for 1468 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-7.txt : 68 ms for 1468 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5.txt : 45 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data7.txt : 65 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data2.txt : 43 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6.txt : 64 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data5-6.txt : 70 ms for 1468 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data9.txt : 58 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-7.txt : 71 ms for 2156 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data8.txt : 66 ms for 1078 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-6.txt : 72 ms for 2156 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data4.txt : 46 ms for 390 words
    Time for file /tmp/data/data6-4.txt : 68 ms for 1468 words
    Word count:[1468, 1468, 390, 780, 1078, 1078, 2156, 1078, 390, 2156, 390, 780, 390, 390, 1078, 1468, 1468]
    Total word count:18006
    Total time 98 ms

So total time is worse, but also time per file has completely exploded e.g. data8 was taking 1ms now takes 66ms !
How can I better diagnose why ? Can I measure CPU time consumption instead of wall time ?
Is it because parallel IO requests actually are slower ?
Thank you for an explanation or any additional tests/instrumentation I could add to better pinpoint the issue.

The bottleneck in this sort of code is reading the file itself, a linear process. How is multiple threads going to speed it up? It won't, and in fact, it only adds unneeded overhead to the process.

@HovercraftFullOfEels each thread is reading a separate file

@yann-tm what are the specs of the computer you are running this on (i.e. cpu)?  physical hard drive or ssd?  if you run it with say, 2 or 4 files, does that make a difference in the MT time?

@jtahlborn, Re, "each thread is reading a separate file." Sure, but if all of those files are stored on the same hardware device, then there's only one of that device, and all of the threads have to compete with each other for access to it.

@SolomonSlow that's a valid point, but not the one that HovercraftFullOfEels made (as i understood it).  that's why i was asking about computer specs.

It's not unusual for parallelism to slow things down more than speed it up.  Parallelism incurs significant overhead, and the only fix is to be careful about where you apply it and measure.

Yes, Hovercraft mentioned one thing that you ought to know when you write multi-threaded code. I mentioned a different thing. There's a lot of things you ought to know. If you think that "files" are pertinent here, then IMO, you're missing one of those things. The performance of your program depends on the hardware, and at the hardware level, there is no such thing as a file. Hardware bottlenecks are devices, interfaces, busses, memory, etc. Ten threads each accessing a different file is no different from ten threads accessing the same file if all of the files are on the same device.

Thanks a lot for the comments I do think parallel IO is a thing, even on a single device but I think I have an explanation now which I posted as answer. it's not a full answer as it does not actually better measure (confirm) but it's plausible. Please upvote it if you agree with the diagnosis

It might be interesting to try this with the files on one SSD and then again with the files on a HDD.  The parallel version on an HDD, there would be drive thrashing, as the comb would have to be moved to jump from one file to another far more often than sequential version.

Specs are an i7 with 4 physical core, hyper-threaded, /tmp is an SSD

Add details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

have you tried with just 4 threads to match the 4 physical cores?


So total time is worse, but also time per file has completely exploded
e.g. data8 was taking 1ms now takes 66ms !

Yes, but the total time for all 17 files has only doubled, so much of that explosion is incurred in parallel.
Thread startup cost, such as you speculate in your own answer, is one conceivable explanation, but that's testable: thread startup time is independent of the thread's workload, so we can get a better bound on it by running the same number of threads with little or no workload.  As I described in a comment, I performed such a test by modifying the MT version of your code such that countWords() does nothing but return 0.  That ran 17 threads on my machine in about 2ms according to its own measurement (and it ran 50 threads in about 3ms), so that puts a cap of about 2ms on the per-thread startup time.  I expect it actually to be only a fraction of that, and I don't expect the cost to be too far different on your machine.
You're more likely to be seeing a combination of other factors, but especially:

you have about four times as many threads as physical cores in the MT case, so if you're getting much concurrency then that program contends with itself for CPU cache space and memory bus bandwidth.  The ST version has much less contention for those resources, especially when the system is lightly loaded.

Other, likely less significant factors include:

context switching costs
general thread-management overhead
delays related to contention for System.out


How can I better diagnose why ? Can I measure CPU time consumption
instead of wall time ?

Yes.  Provided that your system supports JMX, you can use the VM's ThreadMXBean to measure the CPU time consumed by your threads.

Is it because parallel IO requests actually are
slower ?

Most disk devices are single-channel.  Some can queue multiple read requests at a time, but a single-channel device can only deliver data for a single request at a time.  The only way that parallelizing requests to such a device could produce a performance gain is if threads were unable individually to saturate the net bandwidth of device, interconnect, and memory bus, but that's not typically the case.
For some kinds of devices (e.g. spinning disks), there are additional considerations for sequential (faster) versus random (much slower) access patterns.  With such a device, the parallel I/O might be expected really to be slower, but that does not apply to SSDs.  Also, it probably wouldn't be a large effect for your particular test workload, given that it looks like few of the files occupy more than two disk blocks, and some only one.
The I/O in your particular MT program is unlikely to be faster than the I/O in your ST program, given that the latter probably saturates available I/O bandwith already.  But the disk --> memory data transfer is probably not itself slower for your MT case, either.
Parallel I/O (or parallel anything) is not automatically faster than serial.  You stand to gain from parallel I/O to the extent that additional threads can make use of system resources that otherwise would go unused.  That's not usually the case for concurrent disk I/O involving a single disk.  Network I/O is the canonical use case, but not the only one.

So what we expect (hope for)
Suppose IO for file takes 10ms, and counting words takes 5 ms. Thread creation is free.
Because IO happens outside CPU, using memory bus, the sequential version for 10 files takes 150 ms
in parallel version, the IO bus is occupied continuously, for 100 ms, all except the last count could run in parallel with IO, we take roughly 105 ms total (good)
The issue is that thread creation is not free, here it seems to take roughly 70 ms
Each thread starts it's run with an IO, hence is commuted by force
So most likely scheduling is threads sample wall clock time, then are switched, then main finishes creating threads, then the threads get to count. They report a time that includes the main time used to create threads as well as their own.
This is visible as the summed runtimes reported by threads is much greater than total wall time, so we are overlapping (more or less ok) but also counting in our time actions of other threads (most probably main creating the threads)
In conclusion while we do speed up slightly due to parallel IO requests (we end up with 50 ms penalty instead of 70ms) the time to create so many threads makes it not worth it.

This explanation sounds speculative, and I'm skeptical.  Do you have some kind of evidence supporting it?  In particular, although you're right that thread creation is not free, 70 ms (or 50 ms) sounds far too costly.  Also, this doesn't seem to explain why each thread's internally-measured run time is significantly higher in the MT case than in the ST case.

No evidence, I need a way to measure the runtime of the threads+IO not wall time to confirm

@JohnBollinger it does explain why reported time is greater than the runtime of the function, because it's adding also thread creation + commutation time to the measured time

You have several threads that have a measured run time of about 70 ms, including one at 72ms.  Given the overall runtime of 98 ms, the maximum possible startup time for that particular thread is 26 ms, and that's if it starts first and finishes last. I'm inclined to think that it's considerably less even than that.  This is something you could investigate by running the same number of threads with the disk I/O removed.

I stripped the I/O out of the MT version of your program by making countWords() do nothing but return 0.  I ran it with 17 arguments, and the whole program completed in just 2 ms on my 6-core machine with hyperthreading enabled.  Your machine will perform slightly differently, but I see no reason to believe that you see thread startup times an order of magnitude larger than I do.

"it's adding also thread creation + commutation time to the measured time" -- no, it is not adding thread creation time to the reported per-thread run time.  That timer is started by the thread itself, so only after the thread is fully created and started.
